# List Object two Column logic

Tags: c#, list, datatable, dataset

I am looping a datatable that has 118 rows of data breaking them into two column. I would the data in list[0] to be the row1 and row41. Is it working fine until it comes to row 81 and it stops using ColumnTwo because dataTable.Rows.Count is 118 and i + ROWS_PER_PAGE is 120 so it will not go into building ColumnTwo.

> Is there something that I am missing in my logic? so it will fill in ColumnTwo?

```
public List<DataForExcelExport> Fill(DataTable dataTable)
{
    var list = new List<DataForExcelExport>();
    const int ROWS_PER_PAGE = 40;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dataTable.Rows[i];
        var item = new DataForExcelExport();
        SetItemData(dr, item, true);
         if (i + ROWS_PER_PAGE < dataTable.Rows.Count)
        //if (i < dataTable.Rows.Count)
        {
            SetItemData(dataTable.Rows[i + ROWS_PER_PAGE], item, false);
        }
        //New Logic
        else
        {
            int x = (dataTable.Rows.Count - i)/2;
            ROWS_PER_PAGE = x;
            SetItemData(dataTable.Rows[i + ROWS_PER_PAGE], item, false);
        }
        list.Add(item);
        if ((i + 1) % ROWS_PER_PAGE == 0)
        {
            i += ROWS_PER_PAGE;
        }

    }
    return list;
}

static void SetItemData(DataRow row, DataForExcelExport item, bool itIsAFirstColumnItem)
{
    if (itIsAFirstColumnItem)
    {
        item.ColumnOneRowId = row.Field<Int64>("rowid");
        item.ColumnOneFirstName = row.Field<string>("FirstName");
        item.ColumnOneLastName = row.Field<string>("LastName");
        item.ColumnOneOfficePhoneNumber = row.Field<string>("OfficePhoneNumber");
        item.ColumnOneExtension = row.Field<string>("Extension");
    }
    else
    {
        item.ColumnTwoRowId = row.Field<Int64>("rowid");
        item.ColumnTwoFirstName = row.Field<string>("FirstName");
        item.ColumnTwoLastName = row.Field<string>("LastName");
        item.ColumnTwoOfficePhoneNumber = row.Field<string>("OfficePhoneNumber");
        item.ColumnTwoExtension = row.Field<string>("Extension");
    }
}

public class DataForExcelExport
{
    public Int64 ColumnOneRowId { get; set; }
    public string ColumnOneFirstName { get; set; }
    public string ColumnOneLastName { get; set; }
    public string ColumnOneOfficePhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string ColumnOneExtension { get; set; }

    public Int64 ColumnTwoRowId { get; set; }
    public string ColumnTwoFirstName { get; set; }
    public string ColumnTwoLastName { get; set; }
    public string ColumnTwoOfficePhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string ColumnTwoExtension { get; set; }
}
```

expected output:

```
- page 1 
_________
  1 | 41
... |...
 38 | 78
 39 | 79
 40 | 80
_________

- page 2
_________
 81 | 99
 82 | 100
... | ...
98  |118
_________
```

[image: Using new logic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect the following output:

```
- page 1 
_________
  1 | 41
... |...
 38 | 78
 39 | 79
 40 | 80
_________

- page 2
_________
 81 |
 82 |
... |
117 |
118 |
... |
_________
```

and method works properly: there is no data on page 2 to fill second column, with total 78 items in a list.

---

ok, I got it. Last page should have equal number of records in both columns, even if that means that first column doesn't fill page to bottom.

so remove `const` from ROWS_PER_PAGE, and update it for last page:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
    var item = new DataForExcelExport();

    SetItemData(dr, item, true);
    if (i + ROWS_PER_PAGE < dt.Rows.Count)
    {
        SetItemData(dt.Rows[i + ROWS_PER_PAGE], item, false);
    }
    list.Add(item);
    if ((i + 1) % ROWS_PER_PAGE == 0)
    {
        i += ROWS_PER_PAGE;

        int remaining = dt.Rows.Count - (i + 1);
        if (remaining < 2 * ROWS_PER_PAGE)
        {
            ROWS_PER_PAGE = remaining / 2 + remaining % 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that is correct but is there a way to change it to fill page 2 second column. can I update ROWS_PER_PAGE ?  ROWS_PER_PAGE = (dataTable.Rows.Count - i)/2;

Comment: @Jefferson, if you change ROWS_PER_PAGE, you will get different layout. say, `ROWS_PER_PAGE = 20`. then we get 3 pages [1-20, 20-40], [41-60, 61-80], [81-100, 101-118]

Comment: @Jefferson, which layout do you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry just when the i and ROWS_PER_PAGE are greater than dataTable.Rows.Count?

Comment: I see a problem on page 2 it looks like it goes to row 15 on column one and then 16 to 30 on column two. Than there are two more rows added to column one and column two

Comment: I update the post with an image of the output I am seeing.

Comment: @Jefferson, empty rows don't come out of Fill method. `list` doesn't contain empty export items. check export

Comment: when i is 94 it will set the ROWS_PER_PAGE to 2 are we should this is correct if ((i + 1) % ROWS_PER_PAGE == 0)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201562/discussion-between-jefferson-and-ash).

Answer (score 0):

You want the first 40 rows to be put into column one. But in your loop you have all of them going to column one first, then you are checking if (i + ROWS_PER_PAGE < dataTable.Rows.Count) to put them into column two.
When i gets to 78, then (78 + 40 < 118) will be false and no longer going to column two.

If you want the first 40 to go to column one then the rest go to column two, then you should just check

```
if (i <= ROWS_PER_PAGE)
   SetItemData(dr, item, true);
else
   SetItemData(dr, item, false);
```

Comment: Sorry @tomg I want 1-40 in column one than 41 to 80 in column two then some how I need to reset it for page 2 and have half in column one and the other half in column two

Comment: I understand now. What you want to look for then is if dataTable.Rows.Count - i < ROWS_PER_PAGE, then ROWS_PER_PAGE should be set to half of the remaining count.